# Error: could not convert string to float - Django

Tags: python, django, floating-point

This is my code for a small statistics app that I have written in Django.I need to read a string input from the webpage,parse the comma separated values into a list of floats.I am consistently getting the same error.
This is the error I am getting:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'statistics')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,             **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Utsav.Chinka-PC\Documents\Visual Studio     2010\Projects\StatCalc\StatCalc\statistics\views.py" in calculate
  9.     string = [float(x) for x in string]

    Exception Type: ValueError at /
    Exception Value: could not convert string to float:
```

This is my **view.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import stat_func

def calculate(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q','')
    string = query.split(',')
    error=0
    map(float,string)


    output = []
    output = stat_func.calc(string)
    output[9]=1

return render_to_response("templates/stat_page.html", {
         "results": output,
         "query": query
          })
```

Even this does not seem to be working:

```
string = [float(x) for x in string]
```

Being new to Django I had to spend a lot of time on this and cannot figure this out. Please help !

Comment: You need to show us the full traceback *and* the input you received.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks! Anymore details ?

Comment: That's not the traceback, I'm afraid. The web error page has a link to the text version of the traceback, copy that and paste that here.

Comment: Your *query* is empty, however. There is no `?q=..` portion in your URL, so `query` is an empty string, which you cannot convert to a float.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I just pasted the traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just referred to the example given in DjangoBook, wherein they created a form which redirects to itself to show search results. And it does not use **?q=** , how do I fix it ? Sorry, complete beginner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not *have* a query string; your URL parameter has no `q=` parameter:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
```

as a result, `query` is set to the empty string when you try to get the non-existing `q` parameter from the request:

```
query = request.GET.get('q','')
```

This string cannot be converted to floating point values:

```
>>> ''.split(',')
['']
>>> float('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

You'll have to handle the case where the query is empty, and not try to parse it into float values.

Your code will work, up to a point, if you actually passed in a `q` parameter:

```
http://localhost:8000/?q=0.42,8.181
```

and actually stored the result of the `map()` call:

```
float_values = map(float, string)
```

then did something meaningful with the list of float values in `float_values`.